# How to get the content of a Label within a Grid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a label (labelRecipeName) in my XAML that is part of a grid (called gridRecipe) and I want to programatically get the context (string) of that grid.

I know it is always the first element in my grid so I was toying with something like:

```
gridRecipe.Children[0]
```

But I can't seem to get this to work ...
Or is there a better way?

I was hoping to find something like

```
string receipeName = gridRecipe.labelRecipeName
```

But obviously I wasn't so lucky :)
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way you can get the `Label` in the `Grid`. Then you can get label's content:

```
var label = gridRecipe.Children.OfType<Label>()
                            .First(i => i.Name == "labelRecipeName");

var result = label.Content.ToString();
```

Comment: There is a problem with this. It will not just return the content, it will return "System.Controlls.Label: BLAH BLAH BLAH" when we want just the Blah blah blah part...

Answer (score 0):

if your label is accessible by name in codebehind then you can do

`string receipeName = labelRecipeName.Content.ToString();`