# Why do I get a System.InvalidOperationException?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, linq

I'm really desperate at the moment. I'm programming a WPF-programm. I built a simple `XAML-construct` and generated grids and within the grids labels dynamically, based on how many elements are stored in the database. Even though I defined the Label and named it label, I get an `System.InvalidOperationException`. I found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260272/how-to-get-the-content-of-a-label-within-a-grid). My actual problem was, that I needed to get the content of the label in this grid. I made all similar to the question, which I linked.

I hope that you understand what I mean.

Here my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBooks; i++)
{
    Grid grid = new Grid();
    RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition();

    ColumnDefinition column = new ColumnDefinition();
    ColumnDefinition column2 = new ColumnDefinition();
    ColumnDefinition column3 = new ColumnDefinition();

    Label label = new Label();
    label.Content = Books[i].Titel;

    upperGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(row);
    grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column);
    grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column2);
    grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column3);

    Grid.SetRow(label, i);
    Grid.SetColumn(label, 0);
    Grid.SetRow(grid, i);
    upperGrid.Children.Add(grid);
    grid.Children.Add(label);

    grid.MouseLeftButtonDown += (sen, evg) =>
    {
        Label lbl = grid.Children.OfType<Label>().First(k => k.Name=="label"); //Here I get the exception
        string result = lbl.Name.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }; 
}
```

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: why you don't use [DataGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx)? It has ItemsSource property and SelectedItem which you are trying to emulate here

Comment: @PatrickHofman the message I got is: **System.InvalidOperationException**: "Sequence has no elements".

Comment: @S.Akbari Yes, sorry I forget answering you. I don't get an exception anymore, but it doesn't write the result in the console, as it should. It just writes an empty line.

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek I think, that I need to use it, but I want to wait and see if there's a ways to do it in my way. But thanks for your answer, I'll keep it in my mind.

Comment: @SiegfriedXVI Because it is null. Because this `FirstOrDefault(k => k.Name=="label")` couldn't not find what you are looking for, but instead of throwing an exception, it just returns null.

Comment: @S.Akbari Do you have any idea, why it is null? I'm giving the label a content and in the programm, when I start it, there is also content filled in the label...

Comment: @S.Akbari Alright, I think you're right, but you don't have an idea? Of course I'm giving you "the accept" :).

Comment: @S.Akbari Okay, I'm gonna try it. Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: @SiegfriedXVI if you just wanted to check other options, stop then :) This is exactly the scenario for which DataGrid was created. Take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/details-row/). DataGrid is very powerfull and very easy to use

Comment: @S.Akbari Thanks for your help, but it's still empty, I guess it doesn't find a label at the moment, so I startet a new question as you said.

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek Okay I give it a try :) I startet a new question, but I think I'm gonna delete it then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First will throw. Use [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx) that will return the `default<T>` and also [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) (`?.`):

```
Label lbl = grid.Children.OfType<Label>().FirstOrDefault(k => k.Name=="label");
string result = lbl?.Name.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

However, Since this is a WPF project, I suggest use a `MessageBox` or something similar to show the result, instead of `Console.WriteLine`, like this:

Add this to your `using` directives first:

```
using System.Windows;
```

And then:

```
MessageBox.Show(result);
```